# Meaning of "alien"

Tags: meaning

What is the scope of the word *alien*? If NASA sends a pregnant woman into space and she gives birth to a baby there, is the baby an alien?

Comment: If you live in NYC and you don't drink coffee but drink tea, if you like your toast done on one side and if we can hear it in your accent when you talk, you're probably an alien, a legal alien, an Englishman in New York. :)

Comment: @splattne Won't you call such a person a "foreigner" rather than calling him/her an "alien"? Even though both the terms are synonymous, there should be some dividing line that differentiates the two.

Comment: @ikartik90 You should ask Sting this question. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Englishman_in_New_York ;-)

Comment: You are correct: "foreigner" is a more likely everyday usage. "Alien" used for "foreigner" is most likely to be used to indicate legal status. Note that an englishman who is a US citizen ceases to be an alien in any meaningfull way, but could be called a foreigner.

Comment: Do aliens have inalienable rights?

Comment: @splattne: [great minds think alike](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/).

Comment: @RegDwight nice! extra points for Unicode characters :)

Comment: "Foreigner" is considered somewhat deprecatory.  There's a certain kind of more-open-minded-than-thou person who, if you use the word "foreigner" in front of him, will involuntarily mouth the word "furriner", mocking you as the Know-Nothing red-necked Palin-supporter he is sure you must be.  If you must talk to such people, use "foreigner" (and "Oriental" and "chick" and if you have the grapes for it, "negro") as often as possible.

Comment: Anecdote: I'm officially an alien, or I was while living in Japan which requires all resident foreigners to carry a special ID. The official name of that ID is _certificate of alien registration_!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The free dictionary ( http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alien ) says:

> 1. An unnaturalized foreign resident of a country. Also called noncitizen.
> 2. A person from another and very different family, people, or place.
> 3. A person who is not included in a group; an outsider.
> 4. A creature from outer space.

The scope is "strange, doesn't belong in the group." The term alien for an outer space creature takes from that meaning.

By the way: the answer to the hypothetical question is "yes and no." "Yes" because the baby is indeed a creature from outer space (it is arguable whether "creature" means "non-human creature").  "No" because the baby is born of presumably at least one US citizen and therefore not an alien in the context of US citizenship.

Comment: Actually AFAIK, if the baby is born onboard NASA spaceship then it's considered to be born in US territory (just like with ship or airplane over international waters).

Comment: probably, but either way it is still a "non-alien baby" :)

Comment: For what it's worth, the free dictionary definition is wrong from a legal point of view; an alien is an alien by virtue of not having the country's nationality; it does not matter where the person resides.  Furthermore, "unnaturalized" is redundant because once someone is naturalized that person is not foreign.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question on the scope of the word alien: 
I've always used 'alien' synonymously with 'foreigner' or to describe anything that is not native to a specified area.

Merriam-Webster defines alien as:

> Belonging or relating to another person, place, or thing

Comment: I am a foreigner in Japan and my papers say "In case he has ceased to be an alien or died, this certificate shall be returned to Mayor within 14 days"

Answer (score 0):

*Alien* can be used to mean *extraterrestrial* (as in this case) or *foreigner*.

In this case it would mean *extraterrestrial* because the baby would born outside the Earth.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it simply means "[someone from outer space](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alien)". But it also has the added flavor of "no country of origin" because technically the American baby would not be born on American soil.

Comment: But, from a legal point of view, the child would be a citizen of the mother's and/or father's country of nationality, subject to that country's laws.  If either is a US citizen, the child would be a US citizen.

Answer (score 0):

I was dating a woman who just recently arrived in the US, and took her to see the movie *Aliens*.  She was disappointed to find that it was not, as she'd expected from consulting her dictionary, a movie about immigrants.

Answer (score 0):

**Alien = belonging to another country or race**  *SYN*  foreign :
alien cultures

> an alien multiracial society